# How can I set up virtualbox to connect to both external internet and localhost.mysite.com server?

Tags: server, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to use a Virtual Box VM to create a development environment I can share with a few dozen other developers. We are all on an internal network and need to connect to external web sites via proxy server. On the VM (guest) I am putting:

- windows 10 64 bit
- weblogic server
- Several other dev tools

My requirements are:

- From the guest OS I need to be able to hit the internet (ie google.com)
- From the guest OS I also need to be able to open chrome and hit the server webpages running on the guest OS using mysite.com:8007/index.html.

I have modified the guest OS host file such that 127.0.0.1 maps to mysite.com. Ideally that should mean anything going to mysite.com will get resolved to 127.0.0.1.

Our proxy to reach the internet is http-proxy.mysite.com:80. I am able to connect to the internet (pages like www.google.com) as long as I enable the proxy (http-proxy.mysite.com:80) in chrome proxy settings. However I need to be able to enter mysite.com:8007/index.html in the browser and be able to load the homepage. I am able to hit the server using localhost:8007 but I need mysite.com:8007 to work since authentication cookies wont get passed correctly to localhost:8007 urls.

- When I enter mysite.com:8007/index.html in chrome it keeps trying to redirect to the IP address of the host OS 10 . * . * . * and the server is not running on the Host OS.
- When I enter 'curl mysite.com:8007/index.html' in a command prompt on the guest OS it actually does prints the correct response from my server (no idea why chrome is different / not respecting the host file config).

Any idea how to configure Virtual Box or chrome such that the external pages as well as the guest server pages work?

Answer (score 1):

For internet access on VM, you need to configure  network card as BRIDGE, NAT or NAT NETWORK. In your case NAT NETWORK will be better solution, because this will allow you bo be you VM visible in network, just like your Host.

If you have and Internal network you mus have also another card configured for VM for internal network.

To be your VM accessible from Internal Network via http...   the coomputers in network have to setup DNS entry pointing to your VM.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm opening chrome inside the guest OS. I will update the original question. The bigger issue is mysite.com is not resolving correctly in chrome and its redirecting to the host OS ip address. But when I curl the same url mysite.com/index.html in command prompt in guest os it is correctly getting the content and not redirecting to the host OS ip address. Also pinging mysite.com is resolving to 127.0.0.1 correctly. Browser seems to be following its own rules and not respecting what is in the windows/system32/driver/etc/host file.